# Replacing part of a url with bash

Tags: regex, perl, bash, parsing, url

I'm using a bash script that replaces specific text between two strings in a file. It looks like this:

```
GATEWAYURL = 'myDomain.com'
CONFIGFILE = 'full/path/to/config.file'

replacementString1="s/(?<=gatewayIp:).*(?=,)/\"${GATEWAYURL}\"/;"

perl -pi -e $replacementString1 $CONFIGFILE
```

This works great to make a line in the file that looks like this:

```
gatewayIp:"the.old.domain.name.com",
```

Look like this:

```
gatewayIp:"myDomain.com",
```

All is good, but for the life of me I can't figure out how get this to work to replace part of a url. For example I want:

```
redirectUri: "http://the.old.domain.name.com/oauth2callback.html",
```

to be:

```
redirectUri: "http://myDomain.com/oauth2callback.html",
```

I would think this would work:

```
replacementString1="s/(?<=redirectUri: \"http:\/\/).*(?=\/oauth2callback.html)/${GATEWAYURL}/;"
```

However I get the following error:

```
Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

I've tried a bunch of other ways to escape the // and / in the url but can't seem to get it to work right.

Comment: You don't show how you are defining `GATEWAYURL` but apparently it contains unescaped slashes. The simplest workaround is to use a delimiter which does not occur in your text; @EranBen-Natan's answer demonstrates this with `sed`, but you can use the same syntax in Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the shell not doing what you expect with the perl line.

As is, it is substituting replacementString1 and then parsing it into arguments to pass to perl, so that perl's -e only gets up to the space character as an argument.

To force the shell to treat it as a single argument, simply add double quotes:

```
perl -pi -e "$replacementString1" $CONFIGFILE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "s#http://[^/]*#http://$GATEWAYURL#" $CONFIGFILE
```